# Alternative Org Mode Implementations

Tags: org-mode

Has the org-mode text syntax been adopted anywhere besides emacs?

The only place I can think of is that Github allows you to write readmes in org mode and can display it like it can markdown. Are there other pieces of software that support the org-mode syntax? I was thinking maybe there are other editors that support it?

Comment: This isn't really a question about Emacs or about Org mode, though the point is arguable since Org mode's format is native to it. Furthermore, this question is too open-ended: it calls for a list of software (potentially undending, even if the current list is probably very short). It [doesn't belong here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask); a wiki page would be better.

Answer (score 10):

Yes: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tools/

There is [org-ruby](https://github.com/wallyqs/org-ruby).  It is a ruby implementation of org-mode syntax.  This is what github uses to render org syntax files.

Pandoc also has Org-mode support and can convert from and to Org-mode.

org-js is a parser, converter, and editor for org-mode syntax.

There are also various parsers for org-syntax available for different languages.

Of course none of these tools will ever be a fully replacement for the real deal because org-mode and its features heavily rely on Emacs and its environment.

Comment: also, https://github.com/jceb/vim-orgmode

Answer (score 2):

Github allows for text files written in org syntax (say, in a Readme.org file), but I can't say for sure if they support all the features of the org syntax.